# How to create a function that detects the status change value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a function that is executed every second and stores the final status in a text box (there are only 2 status OK and NG).

How can I create a function that allows me to detect when the status of my textbox changes?

In short, I need to store this status in a database, but I want it to be updated in the database **only** when it detects the change of status.

Comment: [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Here is the MSDN article regarding the observer pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern. I've personally never implemented it but it looks like the "right" way to do it. A simpler way would be updating the status of the database directly in the function when the status of the text box changes, but this could provide unnecessary coupling

Comment: A much simpler way (in this context) is to setup an object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When the value of a Property changes (i.e., the new value is different from the old value), the event is raised and a subscriber of the event calls the method that stores the new value in a db. A Control can use DataBindings to present the Property value in a UI (a Control is not used as *storage* for sure).

Comment: what everyone mentions is along the right lines, but i also notice the bold on only.  to truly only update when necessary, you may need to also check the database value on process start so you do not for example update to some initial value every time your program starts.

Comment: Thanks @Cid , never used the observer pattern and works like a charm.